# How to relate user's input to SQL query in order to make a compare

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, variables

How to relate user's input using PHP with MySQL database inside SQL query in order to retrieve the required data.

Where is the error in my code

```
  if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
          { 

           $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
          }
          else { $site_name=""; }



$query_submit =$wpdb->get_results ("
select i.siteID
     , i.siteNAME
     , i.equipmentTYPE
     , c.latitude
     , c.longitude
     , c.height 
     , o.ownerNAME
     , o.ownerCONTACT
     , x.companyNAME
     , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
     , y.subcontractorNAME
     , y.subcontractorCONTACT
  from site_info i
  LEFT  
  JOIN owner_info o
    on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
  LEFT  
  JOIN company_info x
    on i.companyID = x.companyID
  LEFT 
  JOIN subcontractor_info y
    on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
    LEFT JOIN `site_coordinates` c
    on i.siteID=c.siteID 
    where 
    i.siteNAME = '".$site_name."'
    AND 
    o.ownerNAME = '".$owner_name." '
    AND 
    x.companyNAME = '".$company_name."'
    ");
```

this is the dropdownlist  code :

```
                 <?php
                 global $site_name;

                     $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results ("select DISTINCT siteNAME  from site_info");
                      foreach($query_site_name as $site_name)
                      {
                       $site_name = (array)$site_name;
                       echo "<option value = '{".$site_name ['siteNAME']."}'>".  $site_name['siteNAME']."</option>";
                      } 
                 ?>
```

This query if I replace 1 of the variable in **where statement** it works fine 
but using these variable the query doesn't work.

I used var_dump  after the SQL query and before the **foreach loop** and it return the selected  value

```
var_dump($_POST['site_name']);
```

Comment: `$_POST['site_name']` is a totally different variable than `$site_name`. So show us where the value of the latter is supposed to come from. And you need to go read up on SQL injection, and how to avoid that when using the WP database class.

Comment: ok i will edit my question and add the rest of the code